# Spring Security oauth 2 Disable Client authentification on TokenEndPoint with grant_type "password"

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

My application use a Spring Security Oauth2 configuration to manage the authentification.

Currently, my request need those info: grand_type, username, password, client_id and client_secret.

But, I don't need the client authentification (client_id + client_secret) for my application. So, how i remove this authentification?

Here is my current configuration:

AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("khk")
        .autoApprove(true)
        .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
       .scopes("openid")
        //.secret("changeme")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30000)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60000);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/connect").accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
}

public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
}
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery("select us_pseudo, us_passwd, us_enabled from t_user where us_pseudo=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select us.us_pseudo, gr.name from t_user us, t_group gr, r_groupuser gu where us.us_id = gu.groupuser_user_id and gr.gp_id = gu.groupuser_group_id and us.us_pseudo = ?");
    //.groupAuthoritiesByUsername("TO DO FOR RIGHTS");
}


@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}


@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
    TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
    handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
    handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    return handler;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
    TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
    store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    return store;
}

}
```

ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "SPRING_REST_API";

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/connect").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **you need that information to use oauth2**. It's not optional information that you can just remove and get everything working.

Remember that the purpose of the client_id and the client_secret is to authorize your client app itself. Depending on the grant type you are using your client app will need just the client_id or both.

If you want just the client_id you could choose between the *Autorization Code* or the *Implicit* grant type. But first I would recommend to read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) to understand the different grant types and determine which one best suits in your case.